# Calculate next birthday date

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

What would be the easiest way to calculate (and create) next birthday `NSDate` from a string like `@"02/29/1980"`? (day/month/year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

Note that in this case, the date you chose is a leap day so the result will show the following day in a year that is not a leap year.  "Normal" dates will show the same day in the new year.

```
NSString *birthdayString        = @"02/29/1980";

// Convert the string to a NSDate
NSDateFormatter *formatter      = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.timeZone              = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
formatter.dateFormat            = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
NSDate *birthday                = [formatter dateFromString:birthdayString];

// Break the date apart into its components and change the year to the current year
NSCalendar *cal                 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
cal.timeZone                    = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSDate *now                     = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *currentComps  = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSDateComponents *birthdayComps = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                         fromDate:birthday];
birthdayComps.year              = currentComps.year;

// Create the date from the modified components
NSDate *birthdayDate            = [cal dateFromComponents:birthdayComps];

// Check to see if the birthday has passed yet this year, and if not add one year
if ([now compare:birthdayDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSDateComponents *oneYear = [NSDateComponents new];
    oneYear.year = 1;
    birthdayDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:oneYear toDate:birthdayDate options:0];
}

NSLog(@"Next Birthday: %@", birthdayDate);
// Results: Next Birthday: 2013-03-01
```

Comment: Wish you a happy new year...I checked this code...Is there some minor issue of I need to change timezone? as Today is 1 Jan 2013,  The final result "Next Birthday: 2014-02-28 18:30:00 +0000".

Comment: Cheers, that code looks legit. Will test it out soon. So Apple engineers treat people that are born on the leap date (29th Feb) to have their birthday the next day (1st March) on a non-leap year? Some suggest that the birthday should be day before (28th Feb) like Facebook does for instance.

Comment: Just tried it now, I'm getting same results as AnoopVaidya 2014-02-28 23:00:00 +0000, I noticed there was a typo from you lnafziger. You compare with `birthday` not `birthdayDate` also the results will actually be `2013-02-28` not `2013-03-01`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I didn't change the calendar timezone to UTC to match the date formatter, so there was a bit of a difference when the time was close to midnight.  Updated by adding the `cal.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];` line above, and now it shows correctly.  Note that it DOES show `2013-03-01` as the date for `02-29` when there is no leap year, which makes sense since the 28th should always be the "day before" your birthday, and the "next day" would be the 1st on non-leap years.

Comment: @lnafziger +1 If you're changing the timezone on the calendar, you should also be setting it on the dateformatter too.  Otherwise it'll be using the current timezone as the default (which is actually what I'd recommend).  I would also recommend using `-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` instead of just incrementing the year date component. There are weird edge cases involving years...

Comment: @DaveDeLong: We don't need to with the date formatter since we are only using it to get the components.  Of course, it is good practice for many other situations but it is just an extra line of code in this case.  I'll update the year though, thanks!

Comment: @lnafziger this is very interesting because I will not get `2013-03-01` when it is not a leap year. I always get `2013-02-28`. I have tried changing my region settings in both device and simulator to United States but I still get the same date... (I live in Sweden)

Comment: I have come up with some more findings: When using Calendar timezone UTC - 

NSDate description prints out `2013-02-28 00:00:00 +0000`  
Using NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate prints `2013-02-28 01:00:00 CET`

When using no Calendar timezone - 

NSDate description prints out `2013-02-28 23:00:00 +0000`
Using NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate prints `2013-03-01 00:00:00 CET` - So I'm thinking that setting the timezone is erroneous?

Comment: Okay, so @DaveDeLong was right:  The timezone needed to be set on the date formatter too.  I updated the code, and it should work for you now!

Answer (score 1):

Use an [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the string into a date. Then [add a year to it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) by adding a year. And Bob's your uncle.

Comment: so you have to do your own check for leap years?

Comment: I don't see how a leap year would make a difference. Suppose my birthday is December 4. It doesn't matter one iota whether one is dealing with a leap year or not, it's December 4, 2012 -- a known leap year -- and it will be December 4, 2013 -- not a leap year -- and so on.

Comment: but you suggested adding the number of seconds in a year to add a year to an NSDate - how many seconds are in the year?

Comment: The Apple Developer Video about this, "Session 117 - Performing Calendar Calculations" (WWDC 2011) is an hour long :)

Comment: @hd1: it does make a difference if you were born on Feburary 29th, as in this example.

Comment: Pardon me, I now realise there is a NSDateComponents class, please see edit and vote it down for my stupidity.

Comment: @lnafziger : Even if someone born on 29Feb 2000, he will be 1 yr in next year not i 2004!!! And his next dob would not be 29Feb2004. He celbrates on 1mar2001. His question is tricky or we are making it difficult by adding daylight, leap seconds etc... Simply check for the leap year and calculate.

Comment: @anoopvaidya: Of course, but it matters for the calculation. 29 FEB 2013 is not a valid date, so as you said, you need to return 1 MAY 2013 instead.  Therefore it does matter in this context. I did not mean that you would only have a birthday every four years, and if you look at the answer that I provided, you will see that I already gave a solution that works as you describe.

Comment: @lnafziger: yes I saw the code, its nice. But still thinking 15 lines of code, and OP asked for easiest. Isnt it a bad question? If you see a year 1582 October... so many days missing.

Comment: @anoopvaidya: If you have a way of doing this that is easier & fewer lines of code , that can return real dates even with all of the edge cases (like the leap day that he specifically provided as an example) then by all means, please post it as an answer....   I'm fairly certain that my approach here is the best way to take though.  Apple provides a very comprehensive date/calendar class that, due to its capabilities, is not the easiest to use. That's why we see so many date related questions on here.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way (leap year is bugged)

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                     toDate:birthdate
                                                    options:0];

NSInterger daysLeft = components.day % 365;
```